# Rebuild only affected jade files with gulp-jade-find-affected

Tags: pug, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to use [gulp-jade-find-affected](https://github.com/teltploek/gulp-jade-find-affected) to rebuild with a watcher only the affected files. For example, if I do an update in a layout or mixin file, I want to rebuild only the files who includes the mixin.

But the example on the plugin's Github doesn't work since an update of gulp-watch (emitOnGlob option doesn't exist anymore).

After a research, I found [this solution](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/82#issuecomment-55704177) and I tried to adapt it for my case but it doesn't work :

```
 var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch'),
fs = require('fs'),
jade = require("gulp-jade"),
affected = require('gulp-jade-find-affected');

var destJade = './docs/';

gulp.task('templates', function() {
     return gulp.src('src/fr_FR/pages/*.jade').pipe(watch('src/fr_FR/**/*.jade', function(files) {
        return files
          .pipe(affected())
          .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true,
            data: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./src/fr_FR/data/data.json', 'utf8'))
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest(destJade));
    }));
});
```

If someone has any idea to do what I want, I'll really appreciate !

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the [gulp-jade-find-affected](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade-find-affected) module. Thank you for your interest in the module. I've updated it (or actually only the instructions) to support cooperation with newest version of gulp-watch in v.0.2.0.

I found this thread by accident, so if you have any more issues with the module, it would be of great help if you could please create an issue on the [github-repo](https://github.com/teltploek/gulp-jade-find-affected). I'll then try to fix them as soon as possible.

Comment: Is possible use with .pug files?